# What happens to the JFilechooser object when open/cancel is pressed

Tags: java, object, jfilechooser

What happens to the JFileChooser object when the open or cancel button is pressed in java. Does the object still exist or is destroyed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you still has a reference to it, it exists, otherwise, it will be destroyed at some point by the GC.

Comment: So pressing these two buttons just hides the dialog box and do nothing to the object?